# Listing all apps with App Store Connect API returns error ENTITY_INVALID

Tags: cocoa, app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

I'm using this code to get all apps in App Store Connect:

```
let jwt = ...
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps")!)
request.setValue("Bearer \(jwt)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
let session = URLSession(configuration: .ephemeral)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else if let data = data {
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
    }
}
task.resume()
```

But the response is an error status: `400, code: ENTITY_INVALID, title: JSON processing failed`. What entity is this error referring to? And what JSON is invalid? The JWT token seems to be fine, since when using a random value I get an error `401 NOT_AUTHORIZED`.

Comment: See [this information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/interpreting_and_handling_errors/parsing_the_error_response_code). Specifically "Identify Errors with the Request Entity"

Comment: In my case, I was including an empty array for the `scope` member of the `claim` portion of the JWT. If no scope is needed, do not include that member at all

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the reason. You may want to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment in the question, if no `scope` is required, you need to omit it from the `claim` portion of the JWT, i.e. instead of (for example):

```
{
    "iss": "57246542-96fe-1a63-e053-0824d011072a",
    "iat": 1528407600,
    "exp": 1528408800,
    "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1",
    "scope": [
    ]
}
```

Use:

```
{
    "iss": "57246542-96fe-1a63-e053-0824d011072a",
    "iat": 1528407600,
    "exp": 1528408800,
    "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1"
}
```